# Using Core OpenGL to programmatically create a context with depth buffer: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: objective-c, opengl

I'm trying to create an `OpenGL` context with depth buffer using `Core OpenGl`. I then wish to display the OpenGL content via a `CAOpenGLLayer`. From what I've read it seems I should be able to create the desired context by the following method:

I declare the following instance variable in the interface

```
@interface TorusCAOpenGLLayer : CAOpenGLLayer
{
    //omitted code
    CGLPixelFormatObj pix;
    GLint pixn;
    CGLContextObj ctx;
}
```

Then in the implementation I override `copyCGLContextForPixelFormat`, which I believe should create the required context

```
- (CGLContextObj)copyCGLContextForPixelFormat:(CGLPixelFormatObj)pixelFormat
{
    CGLPixelFormatAttribute attrs[] = 
    {
        kCGLPFAColorSize,     (CGLPixelFormatAttribute)24,
        kCGLPFAAlphaSize,     (CGLPixelFormatAttribute)8,
        kCGLPFADepthSize,     (CGLPixelFormatAttribute)24,
        (CGLPixelFormatAttribute)0
    };

    NSLog(@"Pixel format error:%d", CGLChoosePixelFormat(attrs, &pix, &pixn)); //returns 0

    NSLog(@"Context error: %d", CGLCreateContext(pix, NULL, &ctx)); //returns 0

    NSLog(@"The context:%p", ctx); // returns same memory address as similar NSLog call in function below

   return ctx;
}
```

Finally I override `drawInCGLContext` to display the content.

```
-(void)drawInCGLContext:(CGLContextObj)glContext pixelFormat:    (CGLPixelFormatObj)pixelFormat forLayerTime:(CFTimeInterval)timeInterval displayTime:(const CVTimeStamp *)timeStamp
{
    // Set the current context to the one given to us.
    CGLSetCurrentContext(glContext);

    int depth;

    NSLog(@"The context again:%p", glContext); //returns the same memory address as the NSLog in the previous function

    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    glOrtho(0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glGetIntegerv(GL_DEPTH_BITS, &depth);
    NSLog(@"%i bits depth", depth); // returns 0

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //drawing code here

    // Call super to finalize the drawing. By default all it does is call glFlush().
    [super drawInCGLContext:glContext pixelFormat:pixelFormat forLayerTime:timeInterval displayTime:timeStamp];
}
```

The program compiles fine and displays the content, but without the depth testing. Is there something extra I have to do to get this to work? Or is my entire approach wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was overriding the wrong method. To obtain the required depth buffer one should override the `copyCGLPixelFormatForDisplayMask` like so:

```
- (CGLPixelFormatObj)copyCGLPixelFormatForDisplayMask:(uint32_t)mask {
    CGLPixelFormatAttribute attributes[] =
    {
        kCGLPFADepthSize, 24,
        0
    };
    CGLPixelFormatObj pixelFormatObj = NULL;
    GLint numPixelFormats = 0;
    CGLChoosePixelFormat(attributes, &pixelFormatObj, &numPixelFormats);
    if(pixelFormatObj == NULL)
        NSLog(@"Error: Could not choose pixel format!");
return pixelFormatObj;
}
```

Based on the code [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130514052521/http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/202651-caopengllayer.html).